# Xpath doesn't return <table> content within <a> (<tbody> is not the issue)

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, scrapy-splash

The following code is using scrapy + scrapy-splash + Python.
I am trying to extract the upcoming matches (which includes: team names, tournament name, start time) from this site: https://www.hltv.org/matches

My code in the callback 'parse' function is:

```
    match_days = response.xpath("//div[@class = 'upcoming-matches']//div[@class = 'match-day']")
    for match in match_days.xpath("./a"):
        print(match.extract()) 
        # tournament_name = match.xpath(".//td[@class='event']//span[@class='event-name']/text()").extract_first()
        # team1_name = match.xpath(".//td[@class='team-cell'][1]//div[@class='team']/text()").extract_first()
```

It is supposed to get me the contents for every "< a >" element (i.e. should look something like this e.g.:

```html
<a href="/matches/2318355/dkiss-vs-psychoactive-prowince-winner-winner-of-the-future-2017" class="a-reset block upcoming-match standard-box" data-zonedgrouping-entry-unix="1514028600000">
   <table class="table">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="time">
               <div class="time" data-time-format="HH:mm" data-unix="1514028600000">12:30</div>
            </td>
            <td class="team-cell">
               <div class="line-align">
                  <img alt="DKISS" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/team/logo/8657" class="logo" title="DKISS">
                  <div class="team">DKISS</div>
               </div>
            </td>
            <td class="vs">vs</td>
            <td class="team-cell">
               <div class="team">PSYCHOACTIVE/proWince winner</div>
            </td>
            <td class="event"><img alt="Winner of the Future 2017" src="https://static.hltv.org/images/eventLogos/3464.png" class="event-logo" title="Winner of the Future 2017"><span class="event-name">Winner of the Future 2017</span></td>
            <td class="star-cell">
               <div class="map-text">bo3</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</a>
```

But I only get this for each "< a >" :

```html
<a href="/matches/2318355/dkiss-vs-psychoactive-prowince-winner-winner-of-the-future-2017" class="a-reset block upcoming-match standard-box" data-zonedgrouping-entry-unix="1514028600000">
</a>
```

I have tried this in the scrapy shell and the same result.

I tried on Chrome Developer tools and I can see all the contents for each "< a >" in the innerHTML property.

I don't believe the issue is with "< tbody >" as I have come to understand that it is omitted in some cases and added by web browsers, because when I print out the html contents of the returned page from the "response" "< tbody >" is there (by the way, I use a lua script via scrapy-splash to make a POST request to the url and get the html page)

Does anyone know why this is happening? I have spent past couple of days on this with no answer, nor have I any ideas on what more to test to figure why this is happening when it shouldn't be.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `css` selector it was easier for me.

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = ['https://www.hltv.org/matches']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        days = response.css('.match-day')

        for day in days:

            date = day.css('.standard-headline::text').extract_first()
            print('date:', date)

            tables = day.css('table')

            for table in tables:

                time = table.css('div.time::text').extract_first()
                teams = table.css('.team::text').extract()
                event = table.css('.event-name::text').extract_first()
                placeholder = table.css('.placeholder-text-cell::text').extract_first()

                print('  time:', time)
                if teams:
                    print('    teams 1:', teams[0])
                    print('    teams 2:', teams[1])
                    print('    event:', event)
                else:
                    print('    placeholder:', placeholder)

# --- it runs without project and saves in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file as CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', # 
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Result

```
url: https://www.hltv.org/matches

date: 2017-12-24
  time: 03:00
    teams 1: NSPR
    teams 2: MiTH
    event: WESG 2017 Thailand LAN
  time: 06:00
    teams 1: Signature
    teams 2: Beyond
    event: WESG 2017 Thailand LAN
  time: 09:00
    placeholder: WESG Thailand - Grand Final
  time: 10:00
    teams 1: DKISS
    teams 2: Izako Boars
    event: Winner of the Future 2017
date: 2017-12-26
  time: 14:00
    teams 1: Recca
    teams 2: Signature
    event: GOTV.GG Invitational #1
  time: 17:00
    teams 1: AGO
    teams 2: Vega Squadron
    event: LOOT.BET Cup 2
  time: 20:00
    teams 1: mousesports
    teams 2: Spirit
    event: LOOT.BET Cup 2
date: 2017-12-27
  time: 12:00
    teams 1: Singularity
    teams 2: GoodJob
    event: CSesport.com XMAS Cup
  time: 13:00
    placeholder: GOTV.GG - Semi-Final #1
  time: 15:00
    placeholder: GOTV.GG - Semi-Final #2
  time: 15:00
    teams 1: MANS NOT HOT
    teams 2: VenatoreS
    event: CSesport.com XMAS Cup
  time: 17:00
    teams 1: Heroic
    teams 2: Valiance
    event: LOOT.BET Cup 2
date: 2017-12-28
  time: 13:00
    placeholder: GOTV.GG - 3rd place decider
  time: 15:00
    placeholder: GOTV.GG - Grand Final
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes this work perfectly, I re-wrote it with Xpath instead of css and it worked great. But I still don't understand why you need to iterate over the 'table' element and can't do the same over the 'a' element (i.e. changing "tables = day.css('table')"  to "tables = day.css('a')"  will return "None' to all the variables you print in the Result).

Comment: when I check source-code in browser then I see `table` inside `a` so it should give the same result. But when I check `print(day.extract())` then I see that `a` is empty and `table` is not inside `a` but after `a`. For some reason `scrapy` see this code in different way. Maybe page sends different HTML if some options (headers, cookies) are incomplet, or maybe HTML is incorrectly constructed and browser interprets it in different way than scrapy.